# Is it possible to make two-cycle bitbang on STM32?

Tags: stm32, clock, branch

I have a Nucleo-F103RB (evaluation board with the STM32F103RBT6 MCU) and I am learning STM32 assembler. I have set the SYSCLK on MCO pin and make a blink led example successfuly. But then I have faced with the branch forwarding which execute some instructions faster than 4 cycles. And I don’t fully understand how this mechanism works.

This code...

```
  LDR R0, =0x00000000
  LDR R1, =0x0000FFFF
  LDR R2, =GPIOA_ODR

  turnON:
  STR R1, [R2]
  turnOFF:
  STR R0, [R2]
  delayDone:
  B turnON
```

...makes 2-2-2-4 cycles sequence:
[image]
And this code...

```
  LDR R0, =0x00000000
  LDR R1, =0x0000FFFF
  LDR R2, =GPIOA_ODR

  turnON:
  STR R1, [R2]
  B turnOFF
  turnOFF:
  STR R0, [R2]
  delayDone:
  B turnON
```

...makes 3-3-3-3 cycles sequence:
[image]
I understand that some instructions executs quasi-parallel (with the branch forwarding mechanism), so they execution time looks like it takes less than 4 cycles.
But is it possible to make on STM32F103RB a 2-2-2-2 cycles sequence?

P.S. The answer like:

*It is possible with this code*

```
  LDR R0, =0x00000000
  LDR R1, =0x0000FFFF
  LDR R2, =GPIOA_ODR

  STR R1, [R2]
  STR R0, [R2]
  STR R1, [R2]
  STR R0, [R2]
  STR R1, [R2]
  STR R0, [R2]
  STR R1, [R2]
  STR R0, [R2]
  ...
```

...is too obvious. So I search for more intellectual one.

Comment: There's not enough details. Why it is even important to execute something cycle-accurately? Please understand there may be all kinds of caching involved and you are not showing how you initialized the system. You might have incorrect flash prefetch settings, and whatever you do, the MCU still needs to wait opcodes and data from the slow flash if it has not prefetched it yet.

Comment: @Justme There's not enough details for what? The main question is very simple: is it possible to make on STM32F103RB a 2-2-2-2 sycles bitbang? With any necessary settings of your choice. To answer this question there is no nessesty to know is it important to execute something cycle-accurately for me or not. Also there is no nessesty to know how do I initialize my STM32F103RB. Just is 2-2-2-2 sycles sequence possible or not? If not then why? If yes then you may tell which settings shall I set. That's all.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, as you note in your question itself (the "too obvious" solution). This is called loop unrolling, and is done when you absolutely need the fastest operation possible.

Comment: With Cortex-M3 most probably it is not, but some Cortex-M0+ microcontrollers supports single-cycle IO access and then 2-cycle pattern may be possible. Example of other MCU supporting this: https://microchipdeveloper.com/32arm:samd21-iobus-overview . If you need generate clock signal, try use CCO (Clock output) feature or you can use PWM capable timer for generating deterministic fast clock signal.